# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when creating a connection to an Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, tnsnames

It appears that Oracle's java client has a bug - if the `tnsnames.ora` file has misplaced spaces/tabs/new-lines in particular places, you get an exception with the following trace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: <some number>
        at oracle.net.nl.NVTokens.parseTokens(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NVFactory.createNVPair(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NLParamParser.addNLPListElement(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NLParamParser.initializeNlpa(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NLParamParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.resolver.TNSNamesNamingAdapter.loadFile(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.resolver.TNSNamesNamingAdapter.checkAndReload(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.resolver.TNSNamesNamingAdapter.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.resolver.NameResolver.resolveName(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1037)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:282)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:468)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:839)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
```

If you take a C++ application and try to connect with it to the database with the same `tnsnames.ora` in use - it works fine. Same goes for `sqlplus`. Also `tnsping` which should parse this file has no problem resolving any service name. Seems like Oracle were too lazy to `.trim()` the values or something - and it is the same problem with Oracle client versions 9, 10 and 11.

Any idea why this problem exists and what is the exact problem with the `tnsnames.ora` format? (I just remove all white-spaces to resolve it)

Comment: Why do you ask us? Simply re-introduce each whitespace until the problem occurs again and you'll know exactly what causes the problem (at least one point).

Comment: @Joachim - Hoping to get a more educated answer than a mere guess. Also, I was hoping to get lucky and have an actual Oracle developer read this post...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried the advice from GriffeyDog but unfortunately it did not solve the problem - so eventually I too the `check for your self approach`:

Oracle's documentation states that the structure of a record in the `tnsnames.ora` file should be as such:

```
net_service_name= 
 (DESCRIPTION=
   (ADDRESS=...)
   (ADDRESS=...)
   (CONNECT_DATA=
    (SERVICE_NAME=sales.us.example.com)))
```

Ours was:

```
net_service_name= 
(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=...)
(ADDRESS=...)
(CONNECT_DATA=
(SERVICE_NAME=sales.us.example.com)))
```

Apparently the indentation is crucial - if any of the lines in the block of a single `net_service_name` start at index 1 - this exception is thrown.

Only once you add indentation to all (can be spaces or tab) - it works. It doesn't have to look good, but has to have an offset of some sort.

Important note - the only problem is with `'('`, indentation rules don't apply to `')'`.
E.g. the below example is perfectly fine:

```
net_service_name= 
     (DESCRIPTION=
       (ADDRESS=...
)
       (ADDRESS=...
)
       (CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVICE_NAME=sales.us.example.com))
)
```

After searching for this issue to be documented - I finally found out that indeed it is documented at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A57673_01/DOC/net/doc/NWUS233/apb.htm

And here is the important excerpt:

> Even if you do not choose to indent your files in this way, you must indent a wrapped line by at least one space, or **it will be misread as a new parameter**. The following layout is acceptable:
>
> (ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcpcom.world)(PROTOCOL=tcp)
>        (HOST=max.world)(PORT=1521))
>
> **The following layout is not acceptable:**
>
> (ADDRESS=(COMMUNITY=tcpcom.world)(PROTOCOL=tcp)
>   (HOST=max.world)(PORT=1521))

Answer (score 2):

I've seen similar issues arise when a text file is saved with Unix-style end-of-lines (LF) versus DOS/Windows-style (CR/LF), or vice-versa.  You might try opening your tnsnames.ora file with an editor that supports saving in both formats to see if you can correct the problem that way.

Comment: GriffeyDog is correct. This is my experience as well. On Windows, the tnsnames file must have Windows line endings (CRLF). On Unix, Unix (LF).